# Trying to bump rails version from 4.2.11 to 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, gemfile

The current state of my project is that I'm using rails 4.2.11 and ruby 2.3.0. I would like to start using rails 5.0 and keep the ruby version because as far as I understood rails 5.0 is compatible with ruby >2.2.2. But after I executed the `bundle install` command some errors that I don't understand were raised. As an example:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0)

    dropzonejs-rails was resolved to 0.8.5, which depends on
      rails (> 3.1)
```

I found this behavior a bit strange because the rails version is more than 3.1 so in my opinion, this error should not exist. And one more example:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spring":
  In Gemfile:
    spring

    spring-commands-rspec was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
      spring (>= 0.9.1)
```

The spring version for this project is 2.0.2.

Could you please explain to me what does this error mean?

**Update**

Here is the full list of errors that I receive:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    omniauth-rails_csrf_protection (~> 0.1) was resolved to 0.1.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.2)

    rails (= 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0)
   
    rspec-rails (~> 3.8) was resolved to 3.9.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
    
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    json_on_rails (~> 0.2.0) was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
      activerecord (~> 4.0)
    
    rails (= 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.0.0)
    
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "byebug":
  In Gemfile:
    byebug
    
    pry-byebug was resolved to 3.7.0, which depends on
      byebug (~> 11.0)
    
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mysql2":
  In Gemfile:
    mysql2 (~> 0.4.10)
    
    json_on_rails (~> 0.2.0) was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
      mysql2 (~> 0.3)
    
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "prawn":
  In Gemfile:
    prawn
    
    prawn-table was resolved to 0.2.2, which depends on
      prawn (< 3.0.0, >= 1.3.0)
    
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "pry":
  In Gemfile:
    pry (~> 0.10.3)
    
    pry-byebug was resolved to 3.7.0, which depends on
      pry (~> 0.10)
   
    pry-doc was resolved to 0.12.0, which depends on
      pry (~> 0.9)
    
    pry-stack_explorer was resolved to 0.4.9.3, which depends on
      pry (>= 0.9.11)
    
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0)
    
    dropzonejs-rails was resolved to 0.8.5, which depends on
      rails (> 3.1)
    
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby":
  In Gemfile:
    ruby
    
    active_model_serializers (~> 0.9.4) was resolved to 0.9.8, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.9.3)
    
    apnotic was resolved to 1.6.1, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.1.0)
    
    audited (~> 4.9) was resolved to 4.10.0, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.3.0)
    
    chartkick was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.6)
    
    faker was resolved to 2.12.0, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.3)
  
    jwt was resolved to 2.2.3, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.1)
    
    newrelic_rpm was resolved to 7.2.0, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.0.0)
    
    puma was resolved to 5.4.0, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.2)
    
    rails (= 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.2.2)
    
    signalwire was resolved to 2.3.4, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.0)
    
    thin was resolved to 1.8.1, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.8.5)
    
    tzinfo-data was resolved to 1.2021.1, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.8.7)
    
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spring":
  In Gemfile:
    spring
    
    spring-commands-rspec was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
      spring (>= 0.9.1)`
```

This is the content of the Gemfile:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'http://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0'

# db connectivity
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.10'
gem "json_on_rails", "~> 0.2.0"

# web server
gem 'puma'

# for the JSON API
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.9.4'

# Audited is an ORM extension that logs all changes to your models.
gem "audited", "~> 4.9"

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# HAML templating engine
gem 'haml'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'therubyracer', platform: :ruby
gem 'uglifier', '>= 4.0.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails'

# CORS
gem 'rack-cors', require: 'rack/cors'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.47'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'

gem 'fcm'
gem 'apnotic'

gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
gem 'dropzonejs-rails'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'phonelib'
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn-table'
gem "daemons"
gem 'chartkick'
gem 'dentaku', '~> 3.3'

# error reporting
gem "rollbar"

# cron job
gem 'whenever'

# Event machine
gem "em-eventsource"

# Delayed job related gems
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem "delayed_job_web"
gem 'kaminari'

gem 'stripe'
gem 'geocoder'

gem "signalwire"
gem 'http'

#shortened URLs
gem 'shortener'

gem 'rmagick'
gem 'jwt'
gem 'shoryuken'

gem 'omniauth-auth0', '~> 2.2'
gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection', '~> 0.1'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # An IRB alternative and runtime developer console (http://pryrepl.org)
  gem 'pry', '~> 0.10.3'
  # Fast debugging with Pry. (https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug)
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  # Provides YARD and extended documentation support for Pry (https://github.com/pry/pry-doc)
  gem 'pry-doc'
  # Connect to Pry remotely (http://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote)
  gem 'pry-remote'
  # Walk the stack in a Pry session (https://github.com/pry/pry-stack_explorer)
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
  # A thin and fast web server (http://code.macournoyer.com/thin)
  gem 'thin'

  gem 'capistrano-npm'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
  gem 'capistrano3-delayed-job', '~> 1.0'

  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem "factory_bot_rails"
  # fake data for tests
  gem 'faker'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'tzinfo-data'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'

  gem 'rb-readline'
end

group :production do
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  gem 'rails_12factor'  # need for hcb
end
```

Comment: Can you please show the **FULL (!!)** error message? Unless there's a bug in bundler, which does happen very rarely, the full error message should tell you exactly what the root cause of the dependency incompatibility is.

Comment: I think you have only shown us the first couple of lines of the error -- and have cut off some critical information below that actually answers your question.

Comment: Failing that, if that really is the full error message, would you be able to share the full `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`? By doing this, we would be able to reproduce your problem, and have confidence in giving an answer.

Comment: I suggest you delete Gemfile.lock and try `bundle install` again

Comment: ^^ I do not suggest this. You are trying to carefully upgrade as few dependencies as possible together in order to make a smooth migration. Deleting the `Gemfile.lock` **might** turn out OK, but it's a risky strategy -- by potentially upgrading dozens of things at once, debugging breaking changes could be a nightmare.

Comment: Have you tried a `bundle update rails` command? Also you will want to make sure you're using `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0'` otherwise you won't get anything except the earliest version of 5, without patches

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised by the problem as you originally stated it, "I found this behavior a bit strange because the rails version is more than 3.1 so in my opinion, this error should not exist."  I believe you but I too find it strange.

However I see some clear problems in the error output.  In my experience when you have a problem you don't understand and discover another problem which you do know how to fix, fix the one you can and often solve or make progress on the one you are stumped by.

You have a lot of twiddle-greater-than (~>) which is called bundler's pessimistic operator.  This means "equal to or greater than, but only equal to all but the last digit."

```
rspec-rails (~> 3.8) was resolved to 3.9.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

json_on_rails (~> 0.2.0) was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
      activerecord (~> 4.0)

pry-byebug was resolved to 3.7.0, which depends on
      byebug (~> 11.0)

json_on_rails (~> 0.2.0) was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
      mysql2 (~> 0.3)
```

You also have a problem because you are pulling in a version of `chartkick` which is dependent on a higher level of ruby.

```
chartkick was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.6)
```

A radical aggressive approach is to delete your `Gemfile.lock` do a `bundle install` and then you should have fewer errors.  Those errors would make you set an older gem version in your `Gemfile`.

A conservative approach is if you can restore your `Gemfile.lock` which worked before you updated rails and instead of `bundle install` did

```
bundle update rspec-rails json_on_rails pry-byebug json_on_rails
```

Updating rails in the `Gemfile` will force `bundle update` to update all the rails gems, and the list of gems on the command line will tell bundler to update those, but with hope it won't update anything it does not have to, (such as `chartkick` which introduced a problem with the ruby version).

It is going to take some trial and error but you should be able to fix some of the error messages.  After you do that, see if you still have the `dropzonejs-rails` gem, because that problem might just go away.

**Good Luck.**

Answer (score 0):

Your bundler version could be earlier version.
You should uninstall bundler and reinstall bundler.

gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler

if this doesn't work. use the following command
gem install bundler:2.0.0.pre.3